# Can we use word "travel" for flying?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use word "travel" for flying by the airplane?

What I understand is, travel is a general term that can be used for any type of travel while flying is the specific version of it.

Comment: In a certain business context like international banking, if you say "I travel a lot", it could mean you take many overseas business trips. But they are not usually allowed for bankers who are mainly involved in domestic businesses. For them, It could mean to take buses or trains.  **It depends on context** and I don't see a reason why you should use to travel in place of to fly. Contrast "I flew to NY yesterday" and "I traveled to NY yesterday".

Comment: Flying also depends on context. A good example is when someone says i'll fly over. Depending on context, it can mean fast walking, running, sailing, actually flying, etc. All the words used for travel/getting by is just an indication of being in motion in relation to a location(getting to/running from/flying to/travelling/etc.).

Comment: You can use the word "travel" for walking across the room.  It applies to any motion from point A to point B, by any means.  (Though generally it's reserved for longer distances.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, travel may also mean by plane:

> to make a ​journey, usually over a ​long ​distance:

- Between ​school and ​university, she ​spent a ​year travelling, ​mostly in ​Africa and ​Asia.
- I travel to ​work by ​train.
- He travelled over 1,000 ​miles to be at the ​wedding.
- As a ​young man he had travelled (= been to many ​parts of) the ​world.

(Cambridge Dictionary

From Wikipedia;

> Air travel is the fastest way to travel over long distances, but it can be stressful to pack and make sure that you have done everything correctly in order to get through airport security.

Comment: Your examples don't necessarily mean to travel by airplane.

Comment: Hai chiuso con me e per sempre.